# Writing to eclipse Console Output

Tags: blackberry, java-me, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using System.out.println() to print Output to the eclipse console.

```
System.out.println("test");
System.out.println("test1");
System.out.println("test2");
System.out.println("test3");
```

I am getting the following:

```
[2785.375] test
[2785.382] test1
[2785.382] test2
[2785.382] test3
```

How to remove the line numbers before the time stamp values? It is getting annoying sometimes.

Thanks,

Comment: How are you running your code? as Java Application? Give us more information.

Comment: those numbers are timestamps, showing **when** each line gets printed.  you could certainly get rid of them by writing your output to a log **file**, instead of standard output.  not sure if that's good enough.  you can also add some newlines (`"\n test1 \n"`) if you just want to put the app's output on lines by themselves.  that doesn't get rid of the timestamps, but it maybe improves the situation a little.